# Mockito when().thenReturn doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to write tests for my spring controller and having a problem. The following code always returns `redirect:/welcome` though i have `when(result.hasErrors()).thenReturn(true);` which should return `add`. May be I'm doing something wrong. Help me solve this, please.

Controller

```
@Controller
public class SpringController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Autowired
private CorrectValidator correctValidator;

@Autowired
private ExistValidator existValidator;

@Autowired
private Unwrapper unwrapper;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String create (Wrapper wrapper,
                      BindingResult result)
        throws ParseException {
        correctValidator.validate(wrapper, result);
        existValidator.validate(wrapper, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "add";
        }
        userService.create(unwrapper.unwrap(wrapper));
        return "redirect:/welcome";
    }
}
```

Test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
public class ControllerTest {

@InjectMocks
private SpringController controller;

@Mock
private Wrapper wrapper;   

@Mock
private BindingResult result;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller)
            .setSingleView(mockView)
            .build();
}

    @Test
    public void testCreateBad() throws Exception {
        when(result.hasErrors()).thenReturn(true);

        mockMvc.perform(post("/create", wrapper, result))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("add"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are not using the `post()` method correctly. [See the javadoc here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMvcRequestBuilders.html#post%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

In the arguments you pass

```
post("/create", wrapper, result)
```

`wrapper` and `result` are used as url variables, not as method arguments for your `create` method. You cannot mock the `BindingResult` this way. It's actually extremely hard imo to mock it and probably not worth it in the long run. If anything you should test with command objects that will or won't be valid.

Comment: @qiGuar As I've stated in my answer, I don't think there's an easy and worth-while way to do it.